# Inspect null character from Bash's read command

Tags: bash

I am on a system that does not have hexdump. I know there's a null character on STDIN, but I want to show/prove it. I've got Ruby on the system. I've found that I can directly print it like this:

```
$ printf 'before\000after' | (ruby -e "stdin_contents = STDIN.read_nonblock(10000) rescue nil; puts 'stdin contents: ' + stdin_contents.inspect")
stdin contents: "before\x00after"
```

However, I need to run this inside of a bash script i.e. STDIN is not being directly piped to my script. I have to get it via running `read` in bash.

When I try to use `read` to get the stdin characters, it seems to be truncating them and it doesn't work:

```
$ printf 'before\000after' | (read -r -t 1 -n 1000000; printf "$REPLY" | ruby -e "stdin_contents = STDIN.read_nonblock(10000) rescue nil; puts 'stdin contents: ' + stdin_contents.inspect")
stdin contents: "before"
```

My question is this: How can I get the full/raw output including the null character from `read`

Comment: Shell variables can't hold values that contain NUL bytes.

Comment: There isn't a trailing  NULL `\000`, but just between? And can you use external tools?

Comment: oguz ismail - thanks, is there anyother way for me to read in stdin and pass it to ruby/another-command? Inian - thanks, The "before" and "after" are there just to show the issue. In reality there are two null characters on STDIN that i'm trying to show. Not sure what "can you use external tools" means. I'm running this via a `circleci local execute` debugging session in docker. It doesn't have hexdump on it for some reason, other than that I can do anything a bash script can do.

Comment: Do you have `xxd` or `od`?

Comment: @Schneems: If you have `awk`, can you try piping the content to it, as `awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 1`. Remember this translates your input from `b   e   f   o   r   e  \0   a   f   t   e   r` to `b   e   f   o   r   e  \0   a   f   t   e   r  \0` (as capture from hexdump)

Comment: Even if I use another tool I have the same problem:

`$ printf 'before\000after' | (read -r -t 1 -n 1000000 -d $'\a'; printf "$REPLY" | awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS='\0' 1)
before`
And

`$ printf 'before\000after' | (read -r -t 1 -n 1000000 -d $'\a'; printf "$REPLY" | od -c)
0000000    b   e   f   o   r   e
0000006`

Comment: Another thought: is it possible for me to view the number of bytes read or get any other information from STDIN via the `read` command?

Comment: `printf "a\000b" | xargs -0 viewargs` The fact that there are two args means that there was a null byte to delimit them. Does that work?

Comment: what is left when impossible to hold \0 in var? in file